# What Java JPanel Layout allows for center, side, and corner elements?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have this code for a GUI:

```
    package rubiksCube;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;


public class SimpleGui  extends JFrame{
        int[] px2;
        int[] py2;
        int[] pz2;
        Graphics g2 = null;
        int sN;


    public SimpleGui(){
        JButton solve = new JButton();
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        solve.setText("Solve");
        solve.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            Control c = new Control();
            c.solve();
        }});
        solve.addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){


            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent k) {
                switch (k.getKeyCode()){
                case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:

                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_UP:

                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:

                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:

                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_0:

                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_1:

                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_2:

                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_3:

                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_4:

                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_5:

                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_6:

                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_7:

                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_8:

                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_9:

                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_MINUS:

                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_EQUALS:

                    break;

                }


            }


            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent k) {


            }


            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent k) {


            }

        });
        JButton random = new JButton();
        random.setText("Randomize");
        random.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            Control c = new Control();
            c.random();
        }});
        p.setVisible(true);
        solve.setVisible(true);
        p.add(solve);
        p.add(random);
        p.add(new Display());
        add(p);
        setContentPane(p);
        setVisible(true);
    }}
```

Now I want the component (new Display()) to show up in the middle of the screen, while the JButtons solve and random show up in the top right corner. Incase you are wondering, new Display() is a class that extends JPanel and displays graphics.

Answer (score 1):

`BorderLayout` will give you the base requirement, centre and right, but you'll likely need to use something like `GridBagLayout` to accomplish the second requirement if you have more then one button, but `FlowLayout` might be able to achieve it as well

**Updated with an example**

This is a simple example as a proof of concept...

[image: Example]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class SimpleGui {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SimpleGui();
    }

    public SimpleGui() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());

                JButton btn = new JButton("Solve");
                JPanel right = new JPanel();
                right.add(btn);
                frame.add(right, BorderLayout.EAST);

                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, plus 1, do you know how to set either of these layouts up or where i can find info on them?

Comment: You could take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

I would do it with two layout manager.

```
JPanel outerPanel = new JPanel();
outerPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
outerPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
buttonPanel.add(solve);
buttonPanel.add(random);
outerPanel.add(new Display(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Something like this, I did not compile it, but you should get the idea.